# Best way of representing a JSON which has repeating keys for each element in its array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am constructing a JSON which has multiple addresses. I am concerned that the JSON size might become too large and would become a bottleneck for browser and during parsing in JS. As one could see, the different keys, viz. "ID", "FirmName", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "Zip5", "Zip4" are repeated for each address necessarily, which actually grows the size of the json considerably.

- Is there any way I could eliminate the need of necessarily having these keys in the JSON yet have those values for each address? If I had to represent values of "ID", "Firmname", etc as an array [Ex: ["0","firmname","address1here",..] should I be concerned about the order of the values?
- Will parsing become obscure if I represent them as an array of values (rather than multiple key value pair)?
- Will it be a "good" JSON structure (as I would have to forfeit the readability) if I choose to represent it as an array of values directly?

  ```
    "Address": [
      {
          "-ID": "0",
          "FirmName": "firmname",
          "Address1": "address1here",
          "Address2": "13 infinite loop",
          "City": "new york",
          "State": "NY",
          "Zip5": "zip5here",
          "Zip4": "zip4here"
      },
      {
          "-ID": "1",
          "FirmName": "firmhere",
          "Address1": "address1here",
          "Address2": "1 Smith Ct ",
          "City": "San Predo",
          "State": "CA",
          "Zip5": "ziphere",
          "Zip4": "ziphere1"
      },
      {
          "-ID": "1",
          "FirmName": "firmhere",
          "Address1": "address1here",
          "Address2": "12 John Rd ",
          "City": "Newark",
          "State": "PA",
          "Zip5": "ziphere",
          "Zip4": "ziphere1"
      }
  ]
  ```

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: There's no way to evaluate or answer this with the information you've provided.

Comment: Putting it as an array format will reduce the size to about 50%  of the size you have now. Which size are you thinking about that would be a problem for the 100%, but not for the 50%?

Comment: *"which actually grows the size of the json considerably."* Why is that a problem? Are you worried about size on disk, transmission size or something else?

Comment: File size (May need to store it on cloud), and transmission problem

Comment: With Gzip compression enabled, repeating keys should not be a big issue as for file size.

Comment: Suggest you are over optimizing without a legitimate reason. Consider now the parsing you would need to do to use the data would add extra effort

Answer (score 4):

First, large JSON objects can absolutely [crash the browser](http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/), but we're talking LARGE objects. [See  link for a helpful breakdown of cross-browser performance.] So, first, based on this data and some real testing, you should establish whether your object is too large or not. (Because if it's not too large, why bother?)

Now, let's assume that you do experience an important gain in performance by representing your data as an array. It's real life; you have limitations; you're forfeiting readability for performance/space. This change is **absolutely OK** (I mean, what else are you going to do?) if you are the only one who has to deal with the JSON: "readability" is up to you to define. (However, the opinions of your coworkers and/or API users, if relevant, should be consulted*.)

I would recommend adding an property to your JSON object which represents your keys, in order, in an array: e.g.,

```
dataKey: ["ID","FirmName","Address1","Address2"]
```

... etc.

Then, when you parse your object, you could add a wrapper function that asks for, say, the `ith` 'firmName`:

```
data.fetch(i, "firmName")
```

and the function could use this array to fetch the data without you hardcoding knowledge of key order into the code on the other end.

That makes your object self-documenting, and obviously you should make your architecture painfully obvious in your official documentation.

Hope this helps!

*If this isn't working for your user base, I'd recommend breaking down the object into chunks: records 1 - 50, 51 - 100, etc. That's how web apps tend  to handle large amounts of data in real life.